# React: dynamically setting gridArea for components doesn't place them correctly

Tags: reactjs, css-grid, styling

I'm building a Backgammon game in React, and currently, I'm just trying to figure out placing the pucks via css on the board.
The system I came up with is basically creating 4 different grids: one for each quarter of the board, in order to avoid working with 1 giant grid which is over the whole board, which seemed like a difficult solution.
I used grid-template-areas to give each cell in each grid a name that serves as a 'coordinate' of such. This is what my CSS looks like in the bottom right grid:

```
.bottom-right-board-grid {
    display: grid;
    margin-left: 96px;    
    margin-top: -48px;
    height: 338px;
    width: 442px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 'br-6-7 br-5-7 br-4-7 br-3-7 br-2-7 br-1-7'
                         'br-6-6 br-5-6 br-4-6 br-3-6 br-2-6 br-1-6'
                         'br-6-5 br-5-5 br-4-5 br-3-5 br-2-5 br-1-5'
                         'br-6-4 br-5-4 br-4-4 br-3-4 br-2-4 br-1-4'
                         'br-6-3 br-5-3 br-4-3 br-3-3 br-2-3 br-1-3'
                         'br-6-2 br-5-2 br-4-2 br-3-2 br-2-2 br-1-2'
                         'br-6-1 br-5-1 br-4-1 br-3-1 br-2-1 br-1-1';
    align-items: end;

}
```

Basically the system is boardLocation-xAxis-yAxis.

The problem starts when creating the pucks and placing them.
I'm passing and creating a default game start state, with info about all of the pucks and their locations, but for some reason they don't actually place themselves on the correct place in the grid. This is my react code:

```
const Puck = ({puck}) => {

    
    return (
    <div
    className='puck-container'
    style={{ gridArea: `${puck.location}` }}
    >
        <img className="puck-img" src={puck.player === 1 ? 
        puckblack : puckpink} alt="puck"/>
    </div>
    )
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

**They all get placed into the same 1st cell, disregarding the gridArea styling I passed to them.**

In the state, it all shows up correctly, the problem is probably with how React handles gridArea, as you can see here:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: What css is on `puck-img`?

Comment: .puck-img {
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

}